# x and y position various with different devices

Tags: ios, swift, image, coordinates

i am adding image on view with static coordinates and its showing on same position On iPhone 6 and 8 but when i am run in iPhone XR the image position is changed here is my code

```
var xCo = 166.5
var yCo = 328.0

let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_Pin")
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xCo, y: yCo, width: 22, height: 22)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

so how to set image position same on all devices please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

The reason it appears in the different place is because of [safe area](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area) introduced by X+ devices. To properly set your Y coordinate you need to account for this inset. Now since you're positioning your view manually you would need to calculate safe area inset manually as well.

The top inset could be achieved by getting status bar height:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
```

Or you can directly use `safeAreaInsets` and calculate your offset from needed properties:

```
view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
view.safeAreaInsets.top
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to calculate offset ?

Comment: @Green are you generally aware of Autolayout and using frames because you absolutely have to?

Comment: please check my another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58444595/12051575